# Removing ObservableCollection Item

Tags: c#, listview, windows-phone-8, observablecollection

I have created an ObservableCollection and binded that to my Listview. Before my items are loaded into the ListView they are being sorted using Linq and *then* added to the ListView:

```
//Get's the Items and sets it
public ObservableCollection<ItemProperties> ItemCollection { get; private set; }

//Orders the Items alphabetically using the Title property
DataContext = ItemCollection.OrderBy(x => x.Title);

<!--ItemCollection has been binded to the ListView-->
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
```

The problem I'm having is that I can't remove a selected item from the collection. The problem occurs only if I add the `DataContext = ItemCollection.OrderBy(x => x.Title);`. If it's `DataContext = ItemCollection` then I can delete the selected item.

My delete method gets activated once the ContextMenu (MenuFlyout) is being opened and the 'Delete' item is clicked. My delete method is:

```
private void btn_Delete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var edit_FlyOut = sender as MenuFlyoutItem;
   var itemProperties = edit_FlyOut.DataContext as ItemProperties;
   ItemCollection.Remove(itemProperties);
}
```

This is my ItemProperties class:

```
public class ItemProperties : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public ItemProperties() { }
    private string m_Title;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return m_Title; }
        set
        {
            m_Title = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Title");
        }
    }
    private string m_Post;
    public string Post
    {
        get { return m_Post; }
        set
        {
            m_Post = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Post");
        }
    }
    private string m_Modified;
    public string Modified
    {
        get { return m_Modified; }
        set
        {
            m_Modified = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Modified");
        }
    }
    private string m_ID;
    public string ID
    {
        get { return m_ID; }
        set
        {
            m_ID = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ID");
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

**Edit**

How I load my Items:

```
public async void GetList()
 {
    var AppStorage = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    var noteFolders = await AppStorage.GetFolderAsync(@"folder\files\");
    var Folders = await noteFolders.GetFoldersAsync();

    ItemCollection = new ObservableCollection<ItemProperties>();
    foreach (var noteFolder in Folders)
      {

         ItemCollection.Add(new ItemProperties { Title = readTitle, Post = readBody, ID = noteFolder.Name, Modified = timeFormat });
      }
      //code which readers and adds text to the properties...
      DataContext = ItemCollection.OrderBy(x => x.Title);
}
```

Comment: `btn_Delete_Click` is supposed to remove only the selected item in the collection. `MenuFlyoutItem` is a `contextMenu`. When the user holds the ListViewItem the `MenuFlyoutItem` shows the `Delete` option and when he clicks it, it's supposed to delete only the selected `ListViewItem`. I've added `DataContext as ItemProperties` to get the whole ListViewItem Object so it deletes the Item. Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can get selected item from ListView and delete it:

```
if (lvElement.SelectedIndex == -1) return;
ItemProperties selectedProperty = (ItemProperties)lvElement.SelectedItem;

// remove selectedProperty from original collection
```

Comment: Thank you but I've already got an answer. I'll be posting it soon.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

```
ItemCollection = new ObservableCollection<ItemProperties>(ItemCollection.OrderBy(a => a.Title));
DataContext = ItemCollection;
```

It seemed like I had to reinitialize the ItemCollection to a new ObservableCollection and order it all in one go rather than loading the items then sorting. What this did was it had one list which was first adding the items then the other list which had to sort. To avoid this I had do to it all in one go. Above helped me. I got it from [here](http://www.csharpdeveloping.net/Snippet/how_to_sort_observablecollection).

Comment: You might want to consider using WPF's `CollectionViewSource` for sorting and grouping items rather than performing the sort prior to setting the `DataContext`

Comment: Yes. I'm going to be using it for something else rather than this.